# Java - Indenting the line each time a for loop runs

Tags: java, for-loop, indentation

I am writing a method to list all the files in a directory but I can not figure out how to make each subdirectory have one more tab than the last one.
Here is my code:

```
private static void recurseDirectoryHelper(File rootDirectory){
    File[] list = rootDirectory.listFiles();
    if (rootDirectory.isDirectory()){
        for (int f = 0; f < list.length; f++){
            if (list[f].isFile()){
                System.out.println("\t" + list[f].getName());
                countFiles++;
            }
        }
        for (int d = 0; d < list.length; d++){
            if (list[d].isDirectory()){
                System.out.println("Subdir: " + list[d].getName());
                recurseDirectoryHelper(list[d]);
            }       
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("Total Files: " + countFiles + "\t" + "Total Directories: " + countDirs);
}
```

Comment: Just keep a `String` that has the "currentIndent" and add a tab to it when you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Add another parameter to your function called `count`, like so:

```
private static void recurseDirectoryHelper(File rootDirectory, int count){
```

Each time you recursively call your function, pass `count + 1`, like so:

```
recurseDirectoryHelper(list[d], count+1);
```

Then when you do your `System.out.println`, you know exactly how many tabs to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add a `tabSpace` string parameter in the recursion method to avoid unnecessary looping inside as:

```
 private static void recurseDirectoryHelper(File rootDirectory, String tabSpace){
```

In first call,  I would pass `tabSpace` as empty String ("") or single tab("\t") as desired and then with-in the recursive calls for sub-directory, simply pass `tabSpace+"\t"` as

```
     recurseDirectoryHelper(list[d], ""); //<-- First call from outside

     recurseDirectoryHelper(list[d], tabSpace+"\t"); //<-- recursive calls
```

While printing the list, simply use the `tabSpace` for indentation:

```
     System.out.println(tabSpace + list[f].getName());
```

Comment: @user2744307 Thanks for sharing the feedback. If you think this was helpful, then don't forget to accept the answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have a second parameter to store the level at which your method has recursed.  When it's first called, it will be zero.  When you call the method recursively, pass in `level + 1`.

When printing, use `level` as the number of tabs to print.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void recurseDirectoryHelper(File rootDirectory, String indent){
    if (rootDirectory.isDirectory()){
        File[] list = rootDirectory.listFiles();
        for(File file : list) {
            if (file.isFile()){
                System.out.print(indent);
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }
        for(File file : list) {
            if (file.isDirectory()){
                System.out.print("Subdir: ");
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                recurseDirectoryHelper(file, indent + indent);
            }       
        }
    }
}
```